# How to manually restart Node-RED in Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, node-red

**Overview:**

I updated the MySQL Node-RED module and now I must restart Node-RED to enable it. The message as follows:

> Node-RED must be restarted to enable upgraded modules

**Problem:**

I am running the official node-red docker container using docker-compose and there is no command `node-red` command when I enter the container as suggested [in-the-docs](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/local).

**Question**

How do I manually restart the node-red application without the shortcut in the official nodered docker container?

**Caveats:**

- I have ***never used node.js*** and I am new to node-red.
- I am fluid in Linux and other programming languages.

**Steps-to-reproduce**

1. Install docker and docker-compose.
2. Create a project directory with the docker-compose.yml file
3. Start the service: `docker-compose up`
4. navigate to the http://localhost:1880
5. click the hamburger menu icon->[manage-pallet]->pallet and search for and update the MySQL package.
6. Go into nodered container: `docker-compose exec nodered bash`
7. execute: `node-red`
8. result: `bash: node-red: command not found`

**File:**

`docker-compose.yml`

```
# 
version: "2.7"

services:
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    user: root:root
    environment:
      - TZ=America/New_York
    ports:
      - 1880:1880
    networks:
      - nodered-net
    volumes:
      - ./nodered_data:/data
networks:
  nodered-net:
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to bounce the whole container, there is no way to restart Node-RED while keeping the container running because the running instance is what keeps the container alive.

Run `docker ps` to find the correct container instance then run `docker restart [container name]`

Where `[container name]` is likely to be something like `nodered-nodered_1`

Comment: I did try that initially, but was confused by that restart notification which stayed up between restarting the container. Thanks for the detailed clarification.

Comment: I use node-red both standalone and in hass.io.  You can als just do a `docker exec -it <container> bash and log into the container running the node-red service, but bouncing the container is probably the simplest approach.  This handles nodered shutdown and restart correctly.

Comment: There is nothing you can do from within the container that will help, all you could do is kill the Node-RED process which would just result in the container restarting anyway.